# Faster coding for Mouse up, Mouse down function

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a jQuery function that, when the user clicks on a text image description, the function loads an image to a drag/drop area.

I have a couple of hundred images. I'm wondering if there is a faster, more efficient way to handle the code for changing the color when the user clicks on the text? I am NOT a coding expert...  TIA

The code snip:

```
$('#p1').click (function(){
loadImage("../images/myImage.png", 150, 100, '.startDropArea');
});

$('#p1').mousedown (function(){
$('#p1').css({"color":"green"});   
});
$('#p1').mouseup (function(){
$('#p1').css({"color":"black"});   
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>Header</h4>
<p id="p1"> Start</p>
```

Comment: Do you really mean *"is there any way to do this without writing an event handler for every one of the hundreds of elements"* ?

Comment: Why not to do it CSS way? Like `#div a:active {color:green}`. replacing <p> to <a> tags before. Nothing can be faster than using CSS. And then, after some miliseconds of delay, your JS can sustain changes.

Comment: do all of them use the same colors (mousedown green, mouseup black)?

Comment: Thank you to all of you for comments and help.  Yes -Adeneo I do mean "is there any way to do this without writing an event handler for every one of the hundreds of elements!" Sorry for the awkwardness of the way I phrased my question. Yes  – andi, they all have the same colors. -Rachel

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do this in a much more efficient way than writing handlers for every element.  Firstly, the simple part - we will add a class to all the relevant divs so we can select them all in one go, and use that to apply the mousedown/mouseup handlers.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>Header</h4>
    <p class="image-loader" id="p1"> Start</p>
</div>
```

JS - note we are now using $(this) to get the current element within the handler function, and chaining our calls so we don't have to re-select the elements:

```
$('.image-loader').mousedown (function(){
    $(this).css({"color":"green"});   
})
.mouseup (function(){
    $(this).css({"color":"black"});
);
```

The click function will take a little more effort, because although the action we want to perform is the same for every element, we must presumably use a different image source.  We'll achieve this by using a data-image-src attribute on our

elements.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
    <h4>Header</h4>
    <p class="image-loader" data-image-src="../images/myImage.png" id="p1"> Start</p>
</div>
```

JS:
We can now get hold of the data attribute in our click handler and use it to load the appropriate image.

```
$('.image-loader').click (function(){
    loadImage($(this).data('image-src'), 150, 100, '.startDropArea');
});
```

We can chain our click handler onto our previous mouseup/mousedown handlers as well, so our final Javascript is...

```
$('.image-loader')
.mousedown (function(){
    $(this).css({"color":"green"});   
})
.mouseup (function(){
    $(this).css({"color":"black"});
)
.click (function(){
    loadImage($(this).data('image-src'), 150, 100, '.startDropArea');
});
```

Comment: Why did someone down vote this? I appreciate any answers so I'm up voting it. It may not be the best answer. That I am not proficient enough to know, but I simply am grateful for someone taking this kind of time to explain it to me. Thank you to Alex Young